# Error when passing an array from tcl to python

Tags: python, tcl

I have a tcl script tclname.tcl calling a python script (helloWorld3.py ) and passing an array

tclname.tcl :

```
set names(1) Jane
set names(2) Tom
set names(3) Elisabeth
set names(4) Robert
set names(5) Julia
set names(6) Victoria
set output [exec /home/Python-2.7.6/./python /home/mbenabu/vtf/tests/helloWorld3.py $names]
```

getting error:
FATAL: can't read "names": variable is array

is it possible to pass an array from tcl to python?

Thanks,

Comment: It's a Tcl _list_ that maps to a Python array.

Comment: What input is the python program expecting? A list of words in sys.argv?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a value from an array. You can, however, get a list of keys ("names") and values by using `array get`:

```
set names(1) Jane
set names(2) Tom
set names(3) Elisabeth
set names(4) Robert
set names(5) Julia
set names(6) Victoria
array get names
# => 4 Robert 5 Julia 1 Jane 6 Victoria 2 Tom 3 Elisabeth
```

The order of the name-value pairs usually isn't equal to the order the values were set in.

Documentation: [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm)

Comment: I called the tcl procedure like:
[exec /home/Python-2.7.6/./python /home/mbenabu/vtf/tests/helloWorld3.py [array get names]]

Comment: now, in my python script helloWorld3.py I'm calling a different tcl procedure with this list:
   tcl.eval('GetRedhatRelease {%s} array' % sys.argv[1])
but GetRedhatRelease is expecting an array not a list.

Comment: how can i overcome this issue?

Comment: @mba: I'm not sure what tcl.eval can do, but if it can run a script and not just a command, maybe you can construct the names array inside that script instead of passing the key-value list into the python script?

Comment: Yes,
But i dont want to tuch the GetRedhatRelease script.

Comment: I have a tool written in tcl  and i want to be able to use all its functionality using Python script without chaging the tcl code.
Do you have an idea how to do so?

Comment: @mba: no, I don't. I never use Python, so I'm not familiar with the procedure. Also you need to provide much more information. I suggest you ask another question specifically about using the tool in question from Python.